# How Do I know if I need more RAM?

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you know you need more ram?](https://superuser.com/questions/111326/when-do-you-know-you-need-more-ram)

My system is a Win7, 64 bit with SSD, Intel i7 and 4GB or RAM. But I always hear that more RAM runs it faster, I usually use Visual Studio 2010 with like 10 projects loaded in it, soon will be using EClipse also. But when I put one of these gadgets on the desktop it shows I am using 2.4 GB of RAM, so it is not FULL. so do I need more RAM? or it is like well yeah it is not Full but more RAM keeps all your programs in RAM, no paging and swapping needed any more so it will run faster.?

Comment: You need more memory when you have everything you have open that you want open, and your computer is slugish, beyond an acceptable level.  Please note even this measure is not perfect since that could simply mean your doing to many things.  If you have 1.6GB free then your only using a medium amount of memory.

Comment: I find that 8 GBs generally works well for Windows 7 for most uses.  You can press **CTRL-Alt-Del -> Task Manager -> "Processes" tab** to check on current memory use.  If you're experiencing a lot of swap file activity, then that's usually a really good indication that the amount of RAM is being exhausted.